# Grails jquery changes

Tags: jquery, grails

I am brand new to grails as of today and am coming from ruby on rails. My question is if I edit jquery or any code while my grails app is running locally, do I need to restart the server every time to see my changes? or when I save the changes should I see them on my localhost like in rails? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails have the [Auto Reloading](http://grails.org/Auto+Reloading) feature:

> When a Grails application is executed via the 'grails run-app' command
>   it is configured for auto-reloading (development mode). This mode is
>   disabled when a WAR is created via the 'grails war' command.

This feature recompiles your classes so you don't need to restart the application in each file change.